# redirects two tabs in browser

Tags: jquery

I have on page link with attribute target which opens new tab in browser and redirects to given href. How can I before opening new tab refresh or redirect base tab?

Can I do it in jquery?

Comment: Can you please supply with either code or an example? I'm having difficulty visualising what you're actually saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a callback on the anchor tag to redirect. Something in the line sof:

```
<a href="something.html" target="_blank" id="test">test</a>

// Not 100% sure if document.location is perfect xbrowser, but you get the point

$("#test").click(function(e){document.location = "otherpage.html"});
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work